# Enabling select text option in bootstrap tabs

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-tabs

Whenever I try to select text from the active bootstrap tabs, it's not selected and in chrome, it drags the whole content while trying to select text. Is there any CSS or JS trick to enable the select option, so that we can select text or other contents from the active tab.

Answer (score 1):

No any issue in boostrap tabs. we can select any thing in the boostrap tab.
Don't click on anchor tag `<a href="#url" aria-controls="tab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">tab1</a>`.Click out side of the anchor tag and try to select. when you click on the anchor tag and try to copy, it drags.

[image: anchor tag contain area]

Comment: I am unable to copy anything from the tab contents, I dont want to copy the anchor tags, but the text insdie the tab contents

Comment: I don't try to copy the content by clicking anchor tag contain area. try to copy by clicking the out side of anchor tag. see the updated answer, don,t try to copy by clicking mentioned area.

Comment: Brother, i'm trying to copy outside of the anchor tag, that is the main content portion, but still its dragging.